# Systemjs looking for a module that does not exist - how to deregister it?

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I'm working through the Angular2 [Tour of Heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) and have hit a weird block.  I messed up and accidentally wound up with a file named heroes.component.ts.js.  I know this file does not exist because I deleted it, yet I keep getting a 404 error saying `http://localhost:3000/app/heroes.component.ts.js 404 (Not Found)`.  I see it in my browser and in the typescript compiler output.

I tried using the System.delete function in the System initialization script block to no avail:

```
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.delete('app/heroes.component.ts.js');
    System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

I'm using chrome with the dev tools open so I know it's not cached in the browser - How do I tell systemjs to forget about heroes.compnent.ts.js or otherwise get rid of this annoying error?

Answer (score 1):

With your configuration, you load modules on demand so you must still have something like that in your application:

```
import {...} from 'app/heroes.component.ts';
```

or

```
import {...} from './heroes.component.ts';
```

The `js` suffix is automatically added to module names in imports for packages starting with `app` by SystemJS with your configuration

Removing the import should fix your problem.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Also note that IntelliJ sometimes imports with `.ts` extension when moving files. In my case it was caused by refactoring from intellij when moving files.

Answer (score 1):

Check main.ts and search heroes.component.ts string in other files.
In my case when I renamed app.component.ts to heroes.component.ts my editor (WebStorm) also change path to import AppComponent in main.ts

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `System.delete('app/heroes.component.js');` or try the full path.

https://github.com/devslopes/angular2-skeleton/blob/master/node_modules/systemjs/docs/system-api.md

Second did you import something like this somewhere? That could be the error also.

```
import {{xx}} from 'app/heroes.component.ts.js';
```

OR

```
import {{xx}} from 'app/heroes.component.ts';
```